# OpenLayers 3 add info popup element returning null

Tags: jquery, angularjs, openlayers-3

I'm trying to get a  to popup when a vector layer feature is clicked.

This is on the same .cshtml page as the map...

```
<div id="popup" title="Welcome to ol3">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
```

Then in a separate .js file where I am Loading the map I create the popup and
add it...

```
var popup = new ol.Overlay({
        element: document.getElementById('popup')
    });
    map.addOverlay(popup);
```

then in the map.on('click')...

```
var element = popup.getElement();
        var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
        $(element).popover('destroy');
        popup.setPosition(coordinate);
        // the keys are quoted to prevent renaming in ADVANCED mode.
        $(element).popover({
            'placement': 'top',
            'animation': false,
            'html': true,
            'content': '<p>Something happened...good for you</code>'
        });
        $(element).popover('show');
```

However document.getElementById("popup") is returning "null"

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Why are you saying ``document.getElementById('info')`` while id you have given to you popup element is **popup**. Try ``document.getElementById('popup')``.

Comment: That's a typo in the question, you can see in the code it shows document.getElementById('popup')...I'll edit the question and correct.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: It does not seem anything wrong with your code. It should work. Here http://jsfiddle.net/n54xp0fa/ i tried to reproduce the issue but it is working fine.

Comment: can you create a fiddle or change the above one to reproduce the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply @Neelesh, this seems to be a case of the OL3 code changing and running into outdated example which happens quite often as the library changes quite a bit.  Using the example you provided in the fiddle I changed...

```
var element = popup.getElement();
    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    angular.element(element).popover('destroy');
    popup.setPosition(coordinate);
    // the keys are quoted to prevent renaming in ADVANCED mode.
    $(element).popover({
        'placement': 'top',
        'animation': false,
        'html': true,
        'content': '<p>Something happened...good for you</code>'
    });
    $(element).popover('show');
```

TO...

```
 var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
        document.getElementById('popup-content').innerHTML = '<p>It is working</p>';
        popup.setPosition(coordinate);
```

...and that worked to display a popup, now I just need to figure out how to determine which vector layer feature I clicked on :)